# Divine geometry bounding box to equal smaller boxes

Tags: python, python-3.x, geometry, bounding-box

I have a bounding box with coordinates:

```
bottom_left = [10.7510994291,106.5517721598]
bottom_right = [10.7510994291,106.7500970722]
top_right = [10.9005609767,106.7500970722,]
top_left = [10.9005609767,106.5517721598]
```

I'm trying to divide it into smaller boxes that have the same area using Python,
I'm able to create two lists using this code:

```
cols = np.linspace(bottom_left[1], bottom_right[1], num=15)
rows = np.linspace(bottom_left[0],top_left[0], num=15)
```

Here is the result:

```
[106.55177216 106.56593822 106.58010429 106.59427036 106.60843642
 106.62260249 106.63676855 106.65093462 106.66510068 106.67926675
 106.69343281 106.70759888 106.72176494 106.73593101 106.75009707]
[10.75109943 10.76177525 10.77245108 10.7831269  10.79380273 10.80447855
 10.81515438 10.8258302  10.83650603 10.84718185 10.85785768 10.8685335
 10.87920933 10.88988515 10.90056098]
```

I'm trying to combine the lat/long for creating a box, here is the example of two small boxes:

```
[[106.55177216,10.75109943],[106.55177216,10.76177525],[106.56593822,10.75109943],[106.56593822,10.76177525]]

[[106.55177216,10.75109943],[106.55177216,10.76177525],[106.580104,10.751099],[106.580104,10.761775]]
```

Image: [image]

I know that loop can handle this case but I'm still trying to find a better way. Any help is appreciated. Many thanks.

ps: I'm new to Python and don't know much about libs in Python ecosystem.

Comment: The builtin `zip()` function is what you need: `list(zip(lats, longs))` will do the job

Comment: I gave it a try but it's not what I need

Comment: Oh I see. You want the combinations of the first two values in each list, then of the next two, and so on?

Comment: yes, I want to take n and n+1 except the last one

Answer (score 0):

So if I now understand correctly you want to take items from each list, two at a time, and generate the four points that will make up the coordinates of a box.
In this case the solution is `itertools.product()`:

```
out = []
for x in range(0,len(lats),2):
    out.append(list(product(lats[x:x+2],longs[x:x+2])))

out
[[(106.55177216, 10.75109943), (106.55177216, 10.76177525), (106.56593822, 10.75109943), (106.56593822, 10.76177525)], [(106.58010429, 10.77245108), (106.58010429, 10.7831269), (106.59427036, 10.77245108), (106.59427036, 10.7831269)], [(106.60843642, 10.79380273), (106.60843642, 10.80447855), (106.62260249, 10.79380273), (106.62260249, 10.80447855)], [(106.63676855, 10.81515438), (106.63676855, 10.8258302), (106.65093462, 10.81515438), (106.65093462, 10.8258302)], [(106.66510068, 10.83650603), (106.66510068, 10.84718185), (106.67926675, 10.83650603), (106.67926675, 10.84718185)], [(106.69343281, 10.85785768), (106.69343281, 10.8685335), (106.70759888, 10.85785768), (106.70759888, 10.8685335)], [(106.72176494, 10.87920933), (106.72176494, 10.88988515), (106.73593101, 10.87920933), (106.73593101, 10.88988515)], [(106.75009707, 10.90056098)]]
```

Note: I'm assuming `lats` and `longs` are `list`s, and of course the 15th item in each list is ignored since we take them two at a time

Comment: I will give it a try and response later, many thanks